# How to get "Finger down" on a Windows 7 Tablet using KineticJS?

Tags: javascript, html, windows, windows-7, kineticjs

I am trying to develop a remote side user interface for the telepresence software, and I would like to use some `KineticJS` for some of the more flashy components, since the platform is `WebRTC` via `OpenTok`. The solution includes hardware, and that hardware is a touchscreen and I am stuck with no mouse and possibly no stylus as input.

My issue is simple: I would like to know the moment where the user touches the screen with his finger, which is the equivalent of a `mousedown` or a `touchstart` event. However, neither of those events fire in Windows 7, Chrome. I have tried varying the touch settings, such as turning off the hold-to-right click, toggling on and off inking and gestures. None of these had any difference in response whatsoever.

One note is that I can get clicks just fine, but that's not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is `mouseover` same as in iPad/Android, if you are using a browser which supports HTML5 in windows7 device

```
    applications.on('touchstart mouseover', function() {
        writeMessage(messageLayer, 'touchstart applications circle');
        this.setFill({ image: images.applicationshover});
        layer.draw();
    });
    applications.on('touchend mouseout', function() {
        writeMessage(messageLayer, 'Mouseup applications circle');
        this.setFill({ image: images.applicationsimage});
        layer.draw();
    });
```

This is a simple line draw program. which works in HTML5.

this should help if not, please provide more details.